# About listing virtual disks on debian

Tags: debian, disk, vagrant

I have been using Debian Jessie. I've used vagrant recently.

I tried to "vagrant up" a box, but after several failing attempts I gave up.
However, I noticed that my free space has shrunk notably.
I think this happened because the virtual machines I've tried to build, although unsuccessful, somehow managed to occupy that space.

Is there any command on terminal that shows all virtual disks on my linux partition, so I can find the useless ones and delete them?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'll do is to try with fdisk.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

You'll get all the partitions present on your disk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Lescurel, but I've already tried fdisk unsuccessfully. It only shows the  "big" partitions on my hard drive. Because all my virtual disks are on my debian partition (/dev/sda2) and none of them shows up.

Comment: @xchessx, did you run the command as shown with the "-l" argument? Or fdisk /dev/sda? (Or gdisk /dev/sda)

Comment: I've run these instances of the command: first"su" and"fdisk -l" then "fdisk /dev/sda2".  After your reply, I ran " fdisk /dev/sda" and "gdisk /dev/sda" and both showed me only information about "big partitions" again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the vivaolinux forum, the following command solves it:

```
VBoxManage list hdds
```

My thanks to all those who tried to help :)